# How should we fix Client potential XSS for InnerText and InnerHTML

Tags: lightning-aura-components, checkmarx

I am using below code in component to get the values in JS controller and the functionality is working fine, but in Checkmarx scan it's coming as a potential XSS issue and I am not able to fix these issues.

```js
var val = svg.getElement().innerText;

svg.getElement().innerHTML = val;
```

Please help me in resolving these Checkmarx issues.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, this problem arises because the inner text of the "svg" element could in principle be **text** (not HTML) like:

```
<script>do something nasty here</script>
```

When you assign that text to the DOM element using innerHTML it will be treated as HTML and will result in the creation of a script within which there could be malicious code.

Checkmarx is correctly warning you that this is a dangerous operation since someone could craft the content of the SVG element to include some form of hack.

What you need to do is think about why you are doing this. You either need to stop using innerHTML or you need to explicitly process the inner text to remove any "dangerous" HTML before using innerHTML and marking this usage as a False Positive (you won't stop Checkmarx complaining but you will know that there is actually no XSS risk). Take a look at [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326592/filtering-javascript-out-of-html/326612#326612) for some suggestions.