# Security Issue While Rendering Rich Text in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, security, richtextarea, rendering

I am trying to render a rich text content in a Visualforce Page like so :

```
<apex:outputText styleClass="richText" value="{!richTextContent}" escape="false"/>
```

however, I got the following error when I perform the security scan :

> Avoid unescaped user controlled content in EL (rule:
> Security-VfUnescapeEl)

According to error I switched the `escape` attribute to `true`, but now the rich text is not rendered as it should, instead it shows the html text like so :

> < p style="text-align: center;">< span style="font-size: 16px;
> font-weight:bold">Rich Text Content< /span>< /p>

instead of

**Rich Text Content**

My question is is there any workaround to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I've suggested the above (see [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/326612/50252)) as a solution to ensure that your `richTextContent` doesn't include "dangerous" markup. You then render with `escape="false"` and mark this security scan "failure" as a False Positive - you've already made sure the markup is safe to output in the page.

Comment: Hello Phil and thank you for the answer, so the use case here is that 

using the function as: "String safeRichText = stripTags(richTextValue, true)" and then to use it like: "<apex:outputText styleClass="richText" value="{!safeRichText}" escape="false"/>" ?

Comment: That's the one. See if you can also add an annotation in the visualforce page to suppress the False Positive error. If you're using PMD you might be able to add the following attribute to the `apex:outputText` element: `pmd:Security-VfUnescapeEl="false"`, or similar, though I have never tried that myself (and I'm not sure what namespace prefix mapping you would need to add).